# expanding the column size of selectpicker bootstrap class?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-sm-2 ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Item Description
            </label>
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Android</option>
                <option>iOS</option>
                <option>Windows</option>
                <option>Symbian</option>
                <option>Atari TOS</option>
                <option>Amiga OS</option>
                <option>Unix</option>
                <option>Linux</option>
                <option>OSX</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap class `selectpicker` for user to select an option. now i need to expand this `<select>` field. it does not effect the size whenever i change the column size `col-sm-2`.**so here's two question:**
how can i expand this field size? how can i give space between two fields i use `col-md-offset-1` it does not effect on given field (`<select>`).

Comment: Not sure if I got your question, however something like that could be helpful? select.selectpicker {width: 400px; margin-left: 50px;} (Just random values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use custom css for more degree of control over fields. You can use select.selectpicker as selector and apply css on it. I have given the element margin on the left to push id towards right. Padding for making select a little bit more better. You can customize these values as you want.

```html
   

  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                       
            <div class="col-sm-2 ">
                   <div class="form-group">
                           <label>
                                Item Description
                          </label>
     <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option>Android</option>
     <option>iOS</option>
         <option>Windows</option>
       <option>Symbian</option>
            <option>Atari TOS</option>
            <option>Amiga OS</option>
           <option>Unix</option>
           <option>Linux</option>
          <option>OSX</option>
                                             </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
<style>
  select.selectpicker {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
   }
</style>
```